# How can I make IAM authentication work on ALB in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-iam

I used to deploy an elasticsearch cluster on AWS via AWS hosted ES service. I can modify the access control in the cluster to allow only selected resources (iam policy) to access the ES.

Other applications are running from different AWS accounts, so they just need to assume the IAM role before sending request to Elasticsearch.

I plan to move Elasticsearch cluster to AWS container based service like (EKS) and put application load balancer in front of the cluster. The question is how can I let other applications to use the same way to access the ES. Can I make IAM authentication work in ALB?